# html select item whith html tags

Tags: html, select

i have select

```
    <select id="parentId" name="parentId"><option value="1">ФАСАДНАЯ ШТУКАТУРКА&lt;BR /&gt;&lt;B&gt;&amp;#0171;STUC-O-FLEX&amp;#0187;&lt;/B&gt;</option>
<option value="2">ФОНТАНЫ И САДОВАЯ МЕБЕЛЬ&lt;BR /&gt;&lt;B&gt;&amp;#0171;ALEXANDER ROSE&amp;#0187;&lt;/B&gt;</option>
</select>
```

how can i make to show html items not their codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to style the *contents* of your `<option>`s with various HTML formatting. I am afraid this is not possible.

You will have to use a JavaScript-driven alternative.

See for example [**11 jQuery Plugins to Enhance HTML Dropdowns**](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/11-jquery-plugins-to-enhance-html-dropdowns/)

Answer (score 1):

The text within an HTML select option renders as pure text, not HTML, so this is not directly possible.

You will have to use a javascript solution.